# using tag attribute with a UIButton in the sender and trying to cast id -> UIButton

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uicontrol

First time using tag attributes and wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I have two UIButtons that go to the same selector. I would like to add a tag to differentiate like this:

```
buttonOne.tag=1;
buttonTwo.tag=2;
```

In the selector that responds, I'm trying to get this tag out of the sender but being told that `tag` is not found on object of type '__strong id'. I know this way is pretty hacky but is there a simple way to get this to work?

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"you were clicked with %d", (UIButton *)sender.tag);
  [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yap:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
```

Voila.

Or, if you're concerned to use that ugly cast, at least pay attention to operator precedence:

```
((UIButton *)sender).tag
```